# Showing that a function is nonnegative almost everywhere on (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

Let $f$ be an integrable function in $(0,1)$. Suppose that $$\int_{0}^{1} fg dx \geq 0$$ for any nonnegative continuous function $g:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f \geq 0$ almost everywhere in $(0,1)$.

I've tried to approach this problem via contrapositive, and build a function $g$ to make this fail, where $g$ is large whenever $f$ is negative, but I don't know how to accomplish that while making sure $g$ is continuous.

Comment: Can you use that the Lebesgue measure is outer regular? Or that indicator functions can be approximated by continuous functions?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur, I am not familiar with the term outer regular, but I believe we can use that indicator functions can be approximated by continuous functions. Would the argument then be that we construct an indicator function $g$ that is 0 where $f \geq 0$ and is 1 where $f < 0$, and then integrate from there?